# Select specific year & month in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I got a dataframe as follows:

| date | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-20 | 205071 |
| 2021-10-21 | 205071 |
| 2021-04-20 | 21171 |
| 2021-04-21 | 21171 |
| 2021-11-28 | 206054 |
| 2021-11-29 | 206054 |
| 2022-05-05 | 217484 |
| 2022-05-06 | 217484 |

And I would like to only select the following date : `'2021-10', '2021-11', '2022-05'`

I have tried this approach, however, it does not work:

```
selected_dates = pd.to_datetime(['2021-10', '2021-11', '2022-05'])
df = df[df.date.isin(selected_dates)]
```

Expected result:

| date | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-20 | 205071 |
| 2021-10-21 | 205071 |
| 2021-11-28 | 206054 |
| 2021-11-29 | 206054 |
| 2022-05-05 | 217484 |
| 2022-05-06 | 217484 |

Answer (score 2):

For match strings in format `YYYY-MM` use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

selected_dates = ['2021-10', '2021-11', '2022-05']
df = df[df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m').isin(selected_dates)]
print (df)
        date      ID
0 2021-10-20  205071
1 2021-10-21  205071
4 2021-11-28  206054
5 2021-11-29  206054
6 2022-05-05  217484
7 2022-05-06  217484
```

Or month periods by [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) and [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

selected_dates = pd.to_datetime(['2021-10', '2021-11', '2022-05']).to_period('m')
df = df[df.date.dt.to_period('m').isin(selected_dates)]
```